# Profile State showing non initialized status in Magento Admin on the Sales Recurring (Profile) interface

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, magento-1.5

The user made payment with credit card and the payment processed through PayPal payment gateway is showing 'Non-initialized' status in Magento Admin on the Sales Recurring (Profile) interface. Also the payment reference Id is not returned by PayPal in this case.

Can anyone tell what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

`Mage_Sales_Model_Recurring_Profile::STATE_UNKNOWN` is the internal identifier in Magento which marks a recurring profile as having no state. This is displayed on the frontend as 'Not Initialized' and is only applied when the `_filterValues` method returns no state.

The reasons as to *why* it could be returning no payment profile status at all are too many to list - it could be anything from an invalid API key to a processor decline - even a network timeout.

I would do the following:

- Disable all local modules in Magento
- Generate a new Paypal API key
- If you're in Paypal Sandbox mode try to create a new WPP test account and change your API credentials in Magento to make use of this new account (start from scratch)

If all else fails contact Paypal Merchant Technical Support and describe the problem with the invalid reference ID. They should be able to get you sorted.

HTH. Best of luck.